# Get Visitor Posts from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am fetching feeds from the following link:

https://www.facebook.com/wellsfargo/

I want to extract data from **"Visitors Posts"** section. Using facebook Graph API, it returns me feeds only from individual users. I want to get those feeds too in which above page is mentioned

Comment: `/{page-id}/tagged` - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/page/feed

Answer (score 1):

its available in latest version of graph API. [see here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/visitor_posts/).

```
/v2.11/{page-id}/visitor_posts
```

> Shows all public posts published by page visitors on the page. in case if you are calling below graph api v2.7 you will get this data with `/{page-id}/tagged`.